# Don't understanding this instantiate

Tags: c#, actionscript

I'm trying to translate a flash code into c#. I'm not familiar with flash so I'm having some problems. I have fix all problems but this because I don't understand what is.

```
private var map:Array<Array<Tile> = new Array<Array<Tile>>();
```

Is this a list of list? It's used like a bidimensional array but I don't think that this is an array.

Example:

```
    for (x in 0...Main.MAP_WIDTH) {
        map[x] = new Array<Tile>();
        for (y in 0...Main.MAP_HEIGHT) {
            // initialize a new tile
            map[x][y] = new Tile(Tile.DARK_WALL, true, true);

            // set location of tile based on array values
            map[x][y].setLoc(x, y);

            // add tile as a child so it will display
            addChild(map[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Flash, as in ActionScript3? An `Array<Array<Tile>>` could be the same as a `List<List<Tile>>` in c#.

Comment: Quick answer: yes, it is a list of lists. A bidimensional array would be used like `map[x,y]`, not `map[x][y]`.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used flash or ActionScript so I was confused about some functions that seems to be javascript but they weren't.

Comment: And for the record, ActionScript is NOTHING like javascript (so don't use the tag either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a list of list?

Yes. It is. In c# it would be

```
private List<List<Tile>> map = new List<List<Tile>>();
```

There is a difference (in c# at least) for how you access array elements. If you did a multidimensional array it would look like this:

```
string[,] map2 = new string[2, 3];
map2[1, 3] = "aa";
```

With a list, because one array is a "member" (loose terminology) of the other, each has to be in it's own brackets.

```
map[2][4] = SomeTile();
```

Comment: There is probably a much better way to explain this, so comment if something is confusing.